# How can I fix multiple audio streams in an iPhone app from creating distortion?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using several instances of AVAudioPlayer to play overlapping sounds, and getting harsh distortion as a result. Here is my situation... I have an app with several piano keys. Upon touching a key, it plays a note. If I touch 6-7 keys in rapid succession, my app plays a 2 second .mp3 clip for each key. Since I am using separate audio streams, they sounds overlap (which they should), but the result is lots of distortion, pops, or buzzing sounds!

How can I make the overlapping audio crisp and clean? I recorded the piano sounds myself and they are very nice, clean, noise-free recordings, and I don't understand why the overlapping streams sound so bad. Even at low volume or through headphones, the quality is just very degraded.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things:

### Clipping

The "buzzing" you describe is almost assuredly clipping—the result of adding two or more waveforms together and the resulting, combined waveform having its peaks cut off—clipped—at unity.

When you're designing virtual synthesizers with polyphony, you have to take into consideration how many voices will likely play at once and provide headroom, typically by attenuating each voice.

In practice, you can achieve this with `AVAudioPlayer` by setting each instances `volume` property to 0.316 for 10 dB of headroom. (Enough for 8 simultaneous voices)

The obvious problem here that when the user plays a single voice, it may seem too quiet—you'll want to experiment with various headroom values and typical user behavior and adjust to taste (it's also signal-dependent. Your piano samples may clip more/less easily than other waveforms depending on their recorded amplitude.)

Depending on your app's intended user, you might consider making this headroom parameter available to them.

### Discontinuities/Performance

The pops and clicks you're hearing may not be a result of clipping, but rather a side effect of the fact you're using mp3 as your audio file format. This is a Bad Idea™. iOS devices only have one hardware stereo mp3 decoder, so as soon as you spin up a second, third, etc. voice, iOS has to decode the mp3 audio data *on the cpu*. Depending on the device, you can only decode a couple audio streams this way before suffering from underflow discontinuities (cut that in half for stereo files, obviously)... the CPU simply can't decode enough samples for the output audio stream in time, so you hear nasty pops and clicks.

For sample playback, you want to use an LPCM audio encoding (like wav or aiff) or something extremely efficient to decode, like ima4. One strategy that I've used in every app I've shipped that has these types of audio samples is to ship samples in mp3 or aac format, but decode them once to an LPCM file in the app's sandbox the first time the app is launched. This way you get the benefit of a smaller app bundle *and*  low CPU utilization/higher polyphony at runtime when decoding the samples. (With a small hit to the first-time user experience while the user waits for the samples to be decoded.)

Comment: Fantastically helpful... I appreciate your thorough response! And it certainly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that AVAudioPlayer isn't meant to be used like that. In general, when combining lots of sounds into a single output like that, you want to open a single stream and mix the sounds yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you are encountering is [clipping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_%28audio%29) — it's occurring because the combined volumes of the sounds you're playing are exceeding the maximum possible volume. You need to decrease the volume of these sounds when there's more than one playing at a time.